# Convert CameraImage to Jpeg and display flutter on android and ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am starting a CameraStream with ImageFormatGroup.nv21 and like to use the CameraImage to convert it to an JPEG for further proccesing, im only finding older implementations of this but nothing that works now,

starting Camera controller like this:

```
_controller = CameraController(      
      widget.camera,     
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.nv21

    );

//

await _controller.startImageStream((CameraImage image) =>
            {
              processImage(image)

            });
```

I am using Flutter 3.10.5

I have searched for a solution that can convert cameraImage, all the solutions i found is not working, either it gives me error when trying to convert the image or the intrefaces have changed.

A am using an andorid phone to debug, i have tried ImageFormatGroup.bgr8888 and yuv420 also with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

you have to knw the default camera image on android is yuv420 this forma cant be directly used or converted in jpeg or png   ,so at the first time  you need to convert the image in rgba format

```
imglib.Image _convertYUV420toImageColor(CameraImage image) {
  const shift = (0xFF << 24);

 final int width = image.width;
 final int height = image.height;
 final int uvRowStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
 final int uvPixelStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;

 final img = imglib.Image(width: height, height: width); // Create Image 
buffer

 // Fill image buffer with plane[0] from YUV420_888
 for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  final int uvIndex =
      uvPixelStride * (x / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (y / 2).floor();
  final int index = y * width + x;

  final yp = image.planes[0].bytes[index];
  final up = image.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
  final vp = image.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];
  // Calculate pixel color
  int r = (yp + vp * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round().clamp(0, 255);
  int g = (yp - up * 46549 / 131072 + 44 - vp * 93604 / 131072 + 91)
      .round()
      .clamp(0, 255);
  int b = (yp + up * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round().clamp(0, 255);
  // color: 0x FF  FF  FF  FFj
  //           A   B   G   R

  if (img.isBoundsSafe(height - y, x)) {
    img.setPixelRgba(height - y, x, r, g, b, shift);
  }
}
}

return img;
  }
```

this fonction can convert your image in rgba format